# Reading cell content as rich text using Apache POI. Handling numeric cells when using cell.getRichStringCellValue () method

Tags: java, apache-poi, richtext

I want to read a cell value from an Excel Spreadsheet as a rich text, not String, but an exception is thrown when the cell type is numeric and I am using cell.getRichStringCellValue () method . What would be a good approach to handle this problem?

Comment: You might want to read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. Please post your code and the exception. We are not mind readers to know what's going on. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to [follow the approach carefully and lovingly laid out in the Apache POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) (who'd have thought?!). You'll want to do something like:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("input.xls"));
Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for (Row row : sheet1) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());
        System.out.print(cellRef.formatAsString());
        System.out.print(" - ");

        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                RichTextString contents = cell.getRichStringCellValue();
                // TODO Handle contents
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();
                    // TODO Handle Date value
                } else {
                    double number = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    // TODO Handle number
                }
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                boolean value = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                // TODO Handle
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                // Either get formula, or check last value, or evaluate
                break;
            default:
                // Shouldn't happen
        }
    }
}
```

Then add your own logic for handling the contents now that you have fetched them